# TIBCO EMS: Set Priority In Case Of Multiple Receiver For Queue

Tags: jms, tibco, ems

We have same BW application hosted on two different machine(N1 and S1). These application sends message to a queue. Now the receivers for this queue is BE service which is hosted on two different machine (N2 and S2).

We have a requirement where message coming from N1 should be picked by N2 when both N2 and S2 is active and should be picked by S2 only when N2 is down. Same way message coming from S1 should be picked by S2 when both N2 and S2 is active and should be picked by N2 only when S2 is down.

Can someone please let me know how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Set a custom JMS header in the message from the BW applications on N1 and S1 that states which BW application the message is coming from.

Now in the BE services you can then read this header message and check if the other BE service is running (I am assuming they are clustered) in the cluster.

For example in the N2 BE service
Pseudocode:

```
if (custom_jms_header_value = "N1") {
// process
}
else if (custom_jms_header_value = "S1" and cluster_check_S2) {
// S2 is down so process the message
}
```

And reverse in the S2 BE service

```
if (custom_jms_header_value = "S1") {
// process
}
else if (custom_jms_header_value = "N1" and cluster_check_N2) {
// N2 is down so process the message
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the implementation?
Where do I write this code as it is not possible to give conditions in message selectors. Also when my message is picked by N2 BE and both conditions are false, how will the message go to S2 BE?

Comment: No I do not mean use JMS message selectors. I mean set a custom JMS header and read that JMS header in the BE code to know which BW engine it is coming from (N1 or S1) and make a decision to process or not in the N2 or S2 BE code. This code I expect to be written in the BE code possibly in a preprocessor.

If N2 BE picks up the message, it reads the JMS header value and if the value says N1 it will process, and if it says S1 it will check the cluster to see whether S2 BE engine is alive. If S2 BE engine is alive it will not process it but if S2 BE engine is not alive it will process it.

Comment: Assume that both N2 and S2 is active and message coming form S1 is picked by N2. Now in this case my N2 will not process the message as it is intended to be picked by S2. But as the message has already been consumed by N2 (even though not processed), how will the message be available for S2?

Comment: Okay good question. For this I recommend you use a topic and set S2 BE and N2 BE both as subsribers. When a message comes from N1 or S1 BW to that topic, both N2 and S2 BE will receive the message and check. On N2 BE, if the message is from N1 BW it will process it and if the message is from S1 BW it will check if S2 BE is alive and process it only if S2 BE is down. On S2 BE, if the message is from S1 BW it will process it and if the message is from N1 BW it will check whether N2 BE is alive and process it only if N2 BE is down.

This should meet all your requirements.